# Включение .cpp в проект при помощи директивы как к примеру #pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, библиотеки, линковка

Крайне неудобно перетаскивать в исходные файли кучу файлов и еще и лишний не захватить, Проще раз написать код и копипастить иле в отдельную библиотеку включить.
Когда я подключаю .h файлы я указую дополнительную папку где у меня лежат все нажитые за жизнь библиотеки и через **#include <SOIL.h>** их влучаю.

так же и с lib файлами только через **#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")**

Но **cpp** нужно перетаскивать в окно проекта предварительно отметив все нужные, жесть как не удобно.

Суть вопроса: как при помощи кода включить Cpp файлы в проект, и соответственно как для cpp Указать директорию.

И сразу же доп вопрос, Можно ли сами директории прописать через код а не через настройки IDE&

Comment: *"Проще раз написать код и копипастить иле в отдельную библиотеку включить."* - фейспальм... Храните все библиотеки отдельно под VCS, и прописывайте все настройки через IDE, благо в VS это все очень удобно реализовано.

Comment: Не согласен не удобно. например чтобы ingui подключить белее менее полноценно  нужно 7 cpp файлов включить.  Вопрос не  удобства настроек визуальной среды а максимально читабельном коде и удобстве через код . Да я программирую только в визуалке зачем мне хранть код для других иде.  Я более десятка библиотек скомпилировал для середы и спокойно без заморок использую.